# Sending Variable From Php To Js

Tags: javascript, php

I have index.php and I have there some variable in php script.
Now I have jqueryfunctions.js file. I would like to send this variable to this js file.
I am pretty beginning person, and i am totally new to java script.
Could someone tell me how to do this?

Comment: give some code which you tried?

Comment: You cannot set a JS variable to the value of your PHP variable in your external JavaScript file, unless it's being parsed by PHP. You can, however, set a JS variable in a <script> tag in your index.php file.

Answer (score 2):

You Can set the JS variable in PHP file.

```
<script>
    var my_val  = '<?php echo $php_var; ?>';
</script>
```

Comment: Note that if the variable is numeric better to omit single quotes for the php tags.

Answer (score -2):

First of all you must aware about server side scripting and client side scripting. **PHP** is only for server side scripting for process your client side requests. That is you can pass data to javascript only after page load or via ajax.

Comment: One can also embed data from PHP in a script tag.